# Aligning content in a list item for each row

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to achieve the following:

```
1. max 2 cols, x rows
2. list item will wrap - if hide current item then next item will take its place
3. buttons must be aligned in both columns
4. there can be whitespace between the content and the button
5. no CSS3
```

Currently everything looks okay except for the second bit of content in 'BBBBBBBBBB' - link: http://jsfiddle.net/jstime/t7319mpw/

Image to help explain:
[image]

Comment: Not sure if text is dynamic but here's a start using JS http://jsfiddle.net/t7319mpw/5/

Comment: float or inline-block will not set each li to the same height. display:flex might help for young browser http://jsfiddle.net/t7319mpw/9/

Comment: @Dan the height method actually works well here, but there is that delay where can actually see the elements moving

Comment: @Mercury yeah it's not a perfect answer that's what I wrote it as a comment and not an answer.  Also you'd want to check if left or right is taller and apply height to shorter element.

Comment: @GCyrillus the flex approach solves the problem nicely, but I'm looking for a non-CSS3 solution. I'll update the question.

Comment: yes, unfortunately, you'll need javascript to check on each pairs of lis. :( `.                    .`inline-block can be used as a fallback for flex untill you get a better solution for older browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to rely on CSS only you can set `vertical-align:top;` and then give a min and max height to the text container.
In order to align the display:inline-block; you could also apply

`body{
   text-align:center;
}`

**Then the rest of the CSS rules:**

```
#listofthings {
    background-color:gray;
}

#listofthings li {
    width: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}

.text-center div{
    min-height:160px;
    max-height:160px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

**DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/t7319mpw/10/

Comment: max-height limits text display, what if there is more text? And min-height imposes a height that may not be suitable, what if there is less text on both left and right sides?

Comment: I know, but this is just if he wants to limit the text to 160px height. If you noticed I applied overflow:hidden; to it. :)

Comment: If I had to limit dynamically the text content I would definitely use js. It all depends from the requirements, in this case, might be enough a CSS only solution.

Comment: I like GCyrillus solution, the only problem is that if you are working in a commercial project and you need IE support, you won't go far with flexbox :)

Comment: inline-block could be a fair fall back for IE<10 - IE8 .  the IE(s)<7 will need a work around. Javascript could fix this. ;)

Comment: Yes, totally. I would have gone for a js solution :)

Answer (score 2):

Display:flex over used might help for css only test : http://jsfiddle.net/t7319mpw/9/

```
#listofthings {
    background-color:gray;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
}
#listofthings li {
    width: 300px;
   /* fall back for older browser */
   display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;/* middle or top or else */
   display:flex;
}

#listofthings li >div {
   display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    align-self:stretch;
}
div.text-center > div {
    flex:1
}
```

The first comment you had seems to be a good hint to achieve this via js